# Call from Azure Function App to another Function App through API Management

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management, azure-function-app

I am working on a project that using Azure function apps as API, for eg. FuncA and FuncB.
All the function apps are behind the API Management with B2C authentication.

I want to make a call from FunA logic code to FuncB but must be through the APIM Gateway. Is there any solution for this?
Thank you all!

Comment: Did you already considerated to use Durable Functions? Or to aggregate the calls to FuncA and B in one single APIM call? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/api-aggregation-using-azure-apim

Comment: I don't get your question. Don't you know the URL and operations for FuncB in APIM? Can't you make call in FuncA to the APIM url and operations?